# Using jQuery .animate() within a for loop, any reason against this? (Hasn't worked )

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using this code (much easier to illustrate in a Fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/rECyh/

I am attempting to spray the divs out in a radial motion, i think this code will work but it has no effect, can anyone spot the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you have an extra space:

```
$('#menuButton').click(function(){
    for (i=1, j=0, k=150; i<=5; i++, j+=30, k-=30){
        $('.spinner#item' + i).animate({
            left: '+=' + j,
            bottom: '+=' + k
          }, 500);
    }
});
```

That is, `.spinner #item` should be `.spinner#item`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong: `$('.spinner #item' + i)` should be `$('.spinner#item' + i)` -- note the lack of a space between the class and id in my correction. Your current selector says "Find an element with an id of "item + i" that is a descendant of .spinner".

That's the only change I made and now it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/rECyh/1/

Comment: God, i was over thinking the problem and it turned out to be a selector issue. Doh!